# Laravel 5 uploading zip file showing Undefined variable: e

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've created a file upload method and the file uploading with the file extension like `jpg, png` etc are successful. However, when I upload a zip file, it says me "`Undefined variable: e`". To find, I did `dd()` at the beginning of the respective method but it still says the above error. My route is as below:

```
Route::post('media/savedata/{id?}/{page?}', 'Administrator\MedialibraryController@savedata');
```

**The method is as below:**

```
public function savedata($id, $page, Request $request) {
 ...
}
```

**The content of the "network" tab is as below:**

```
Request URL: http://localhost/stmd/administrator/media/savedata/0/1
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

------WebKitFormBoundaryaHtERzAAThbQB4ae
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

TXLvBGRXrdjpQbhAjm18MTxkiHamauvcjhKBhl6n
------WebKitFormBoundaryaHtERzAAThbQB4ae
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileType"

I
------WebKitFormBoundaryaHtERzAAThbQB4ae
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"; filename="gradle-3.5-bin.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
```

My intention is: If zip file is upload then it will redirect to another page however, I can't do this because even `dd()` is not working.

**UPDATE:**

Below is the Laravel Log:

```
[2018-07-23 11:59:51] local.ERROR: Undefined variable: e {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: e at /var/www/html/stmd/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:76)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/stmd/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(76): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/html/s...', 76, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/stmd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(83): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Exceptions\\PostTooLargeException))
#2 /var/www/html/stmd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(55): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->handleException(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Exceptions\\PostTooLargeException))
#3 /var/www/html/stmd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#4 /var/www/html/stmd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/stmd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#6 /var/www/html/stmd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 /var/www/html/stmd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/html/stmd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 /var/www/html/stmd/public/index.php(58): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 /var/www/html/stmd/index.php(4): include('/var/www/html/s...')
#11 {main}
"}
```

My Handler.php content is below:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if($this->isHttpException($exception)){
            $logFile = 'laravel.log';

            Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$logFile);
            //echo Route::getCurrentRoute()->getAction();



            //echo $exception->getStatusCode();exit;
            switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {

                case 404:
                    Log::info('Unable to find page.');
                    return response()->view('errors.404',[],404);

                    break;

                case 500:

                    Log::error('In Server is really going wrong.');
                    return response()->view('errors.500',[],500);

                    break;
                 default:
                    return $this->renderHttpException($e);
                break;

            }

        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it show a file or line number with the error?

Comment: ErrorException 
…/app/Exceptions/Handler.php76

Comment: Nothing except the above.

Comment: what file size of zip file is?

Comment: @DeepakPatel 73.3 MB

Comment: could you check `./storage/logs/laravel.log`? it should contain more of the error

Comment: @Quezler nothing extra in log file. question updated with content of the log file.

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara It might be because of larger file size.

Comment: the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file does not have more than `76` lines by default, you appear to have modified it, can you share (part of) that file around line `76` please?

Comment: @DeepakPatel I think so. because I upload a small zip file and it shows me the error. So, how can I fix it?

Comment: @Quezler - question updated

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara do client side validation using javascript or jquery to handle file size

Comment: @DeepakPatel but never rely on it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`return $this->renderHttpException($e);`

to

`return $this->renderHttpException($exception);`

in

`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

Comment: So you are sending a too large post, you should configure post_max_size and upload_max_filesize on your php.ini file to be larger than your file size

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara good, that means that your exception handler is working again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the FileException exception inside your exception handler at `app/Exceptions/Handler.php.` Update the render method to add in the code you need. For example, if you'd like to return a validation exception, you will need to handle the validation inside the exception handler for the FileException exception.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException) {
        // create a validator and validate to throw a new ValidationException
        return Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'your_file_input' => 'required|file|size:5000',
        ])->validate();
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

This is untested, but should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException)
            return \Redirect::to('administrator/media')->with('errorMessage', 'Please upload an image.');
```

Comment: code-only answers don't help, please, describe provided solution in details